# Find ~/.aws to Setup Boto3 Credentials and Region in Cloud9

Tags: ubuntu, cloud9-ide, boto3

I recently installed boto3 in Cloud9 IDE which uses Ubuntu. Below is what I see in the terminal:

```
~/workspace (master) $ pip install boto3
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): boto3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Then I tried to set Credentials and Region, but I can't locate the /.aws folder.

I tried finding the folder as follows:

```
~ $ find aws
find: `aws': No such file or directory
```

I also tried searching manually for the folder but to no avail. How can I find the directory so I can setup my credentials and region?

Comment: Find uses exact matching so you'd need to run `find .aws` in order to find that folder. I don't know enough about about boto3 to be of much more help than this but this guide seems to indicate that you need aws cli installed to configure credentials and region: http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html

Comment: aws cli was what I was missing. Thanks a bunch, and I'd be happy to accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need aws cli installed to configure credentials and region. See this [Boto3 guide](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html).

Comment: I am also facing the same error - I am able to configure credentials and regions but still I cannot do the pip install boto3. I can download it as a subfolder, but it does not communicate with my app.py.